# For these 2 tables: Product(ProductID, ProductName), Sales(SalesOrderID, ProductID, SaleDate) -

Tags: sql-server

For these 2 tables:

> Product(ProductID, ProductName)
>
> Sales(SalesOrderID, ProductID, SaleDate)

- Get the list of Products that were sold last year. Get the list of
- Products that were NOT sold last year.

Comment: Can you show us what you achieved?

Comment: At least try to do something and in case you are facing any trouble then we can help you out.

Comment: Someone gave an up-vote for this question. Really it deserves an up-vote?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sold last year

```
select Product.ProductName from Product inner join Sales on Product.ProductID = Sales.ProductID where year(Sales.SaleDate) = year(getdate())-1
```

NOT sold last year

```
select Product.ProductName from Product where ProductID not in ( select ProductID in Sales where year(Sales.SaleDate) = year(getdate())-1)
```

Comment: Any explanation for downvote ?? please :/

Comment: Last means last not previous. You have some syntax errors.

Comment: Doesn't last year mean previous year ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is preferable solution that is `SARG`able:

```
select distinct p.ProductID, p.ProductName 
from Product p
join Sales s on p.ProductID = s.ProductID
where s.SaleDate >= cast (cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(8)) + '0101' as date)
```

and:

```
select distinct p.ProductID, p.ProductName 
from Product p
left join Sales s on p.ProductID = s.ProductID
             and s.SaleDate >= cast (cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(8)) + '0101' as date)
where s.ProductID is null
```

Comment: `s.SaleDate >= cast` won't this' search last years instead of last year  ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi, you will get `s.SaleDate >='20150101'`. Did you mean something else in `last`?

Comment: But  sir  if i have data on 16/08/2014 , 12/01/2013 , 10/06/2012 , then  what will your query return on the term ` Products that were sold last year`

Comment: Nothing, because last year is 2015

Comment: You said me why I used LEFT JOIN. How about you?

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều, I am filtering NULLs! You are just left joining...without any sense

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều, downvoting on correct answer just because you are angry is also nonsense.